# Remove UIimage from custom uitablecell view

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I want to remove a IBOutlet UIimage from certain table cells:

I have a custom table cell comprising an image, a label, a subtitle...

cellIcon, cellHead, cellStandfirst

Some cells wont have an image, so I want the label and subtitle to extend backwards to fill the space left by the image (Just as a standard UITable behaves if it doesn't have a custom cell class)

Currently I'm calling

```
[cell shortCell:cell.bounds.size.width];
```

from the tableViewController, which calls

```
- (void)shortCell:(float)myfloat; {
    [cellHead setFrame:CGRectMake(
        CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN, 
        3.0f, 
        myfloat - (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2), 
        24.0f)];
    [cellStandfirst setFrame:CGRectMake(
        CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN, 
        25.0f, 
        myfloat - (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2), 
        34.0f)];
}
```

which works fine but it strikes me that the default table view must remove the image rather than resize the labels.

I tried putting variants of

```
[cellIcon removeFromSuperview];
```

in the cell class, and

```
[cell.cellIcon remove];
```

in the tableview controller but can't get anything to work

Is it possible to remove a table cell image from certain cells so the labels resize automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used this code

```
if ( __what-test-is-needed__) {
    [cell cellIcon:@"your_image.png"];

} else {
    [cell cellIcon:nil];
    [cell shortCell:cell.bounds.size.width];
}
```

Then in the cell class

```
#define CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH 320.0f
#define CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN 10.0f

@implementation StoryCellViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {

    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code.
    }
    return self;
}



- (void)cellHead:(NSString *)_text;{
    cellHead.text = _text;
    //NSLog(@"Width: %f", self.bounds.size.width);
}

- (void)cellIcon:(NSString *)_text;{
    cellIcon.image = [UIImage imageNamed:_text];
}

- (void)cellStandfirst:(NSString *)_text;{
    cellStandfirst.text = _text;


}

- (void)shortCell:(float)myfloat; {
    // NSLog(@"Width: %f", self.bounds.size.width);
    // NSLog(@"Float: %f", myfloat);
    [cellHead setFrame:CGRectMake(
                               CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN, 
                               4.0f, 
                               myfloat - (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2), 
                               24.0f)];
    [cellStandfirst setFrame:CGRectMake(
                                    CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN, 
                                    26.0f, 
                                    myfloat - (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2), 
                                    34.0f)];
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {

    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just try:

```
cell.cellIcon = nil;
```

Or:

```
[cell setCellIcon:nil];
```

I don't know it will work or not, but you just try.

Comment: I'm already calling that, it just places a nil image (ie no image) into the uimageview, but it doesn't remove the space that the uimageview allocates itself ion the view

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
cellIcon.hidden=YES;
```

property to do so......

Answer (score 0):

There is no way a subview can fill the empty spaces automatically. You will have to stick with your current method.

If you are going to remove the empty `cellIcon` from the `superview`, you must keep in mind that the cells are reused. So you will have to re-initialize it programmatically if its `nil`.